# How to get favicon to work with backblaze-b2?

Tags: backblaze

I've created a static webpage hosted in a backblaze-b2 bucket.

I've put my `favicon.ico` file in the root of that bucket, and even tried including the following html in my page:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

The favicon does not appear.

How to get a static webpage hosted with backblaze-b2 to show up?

Comment: is the ico file in the same directory as the document? is the server set up to serve .ico files as static resources?  is any request filtering blocking .ico files? when in the browser debug tools, is a request made to get the ico file, and if so what is its response code?

Comment: @FrankThomas your comment was a lifesaver. Debug tools showed the request was 404 not found, and what worked for me was adding a transform rule in cloudflare rewriting that favicon url. Thank you!